# In trig substitution integration problems why is the square root of tan^2(theta) = tan(theta)?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I mean...for a number ...say 64, we always take its positive square root $\sqrt{64} = 8$, whereas an algebraic number (i.e., a *variable*) $x^2$, applying the square root to it gives, by definition, $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$

If what I wrote above is all true...then why in trig substitutions is, for example, $\sqrt{tan^2{\theta}} = tan(\theta)$?  Theta is an integration variable...so shouldn't it really be $|tan(\theta)|$?

I think that I may be missing some pre-calculus knowledge here.

Thanks,

Comment: What is an "integration variable?"

Comment: Hi @zz20s, say, integration against the differential $d\theta$ ... thanks,

Comment: You can assume $\tan(\theta)<0$ just as easily as one can assume $\tan(\theta) \ge 0$. I think we don't usually write both cases because of the "simpleness" (like $\tan(\theta)$ can be integrated in a similar way to that of $-\tan(\theta)$, the constant multiple is just a difference of signs.

Comment: Hi @randomgirl, hmm....or perhaps, knowing the lower and upper limits of integration, say from 0 to $\large \frac{\pi}{2}$, we know that tan is always positive, and hence we take the positive square root? Does that sound right?  Thanks,

Comment: Yes if we are integrating from 0 to pi/2, then yes tan will be positive and so $\sqrt{\tan^2(\theta)}=\tan(\theta)$.

Comment: What do you mean by that? You could easily write $\mathrm{d}x$ or $\sqrt{\theta^2}=|\theta|$

Comment: Right ...ah...so it's really the context, then.  But you *do* agree that taking the square root of an "algebraic number" ...gives  you the absolute value of it, right? So that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$?  Thanks so much, @randomgirl,

Comment: Yes. I think you misunderstand that $\theta$ is only used for trig functions. That is not necessarily true. It's just a convention. Please tell me if I am incorrect.

Comment: Another example if we are integrating $\sqrt{\tan^2(\theta)}$ from -pi/2 to 0, then we know tan is negative there so $\sqrt{\tan^2(\theta)}=-\tan(\theta)$

Comment: And yes. $\sqrt{(f(x))^2}=|f(x)|$

Comment: ah, got it @randomgirl - so just make sure that taking positive square roots will always yield a positive number, so the output $| x |$ helps make it happen.  (not considering complex square roots...) right?  Thanks for your help,

Comment: Thanks for the helpful discussions @randomgirl :-)

Comment: Right $|f(x)|=f(x)$ if $f(x) \ge 0$ and $|f(x)|=-f(x)$ if $f(x) <0$... And you can determine if $f(x)$ is negative or positive based on your limits of integration... Sometimes you made need to break up your integral...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this example might sum up our discussion from above: $\int_\frac{-\pi}{2}^\frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{\tan^2(\theta)} d \theta=\int_\frac{-\pi}{2}^0 -\tan(\theta) d \theta+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \tan(\theta)d \theta$ I had to break up the integral because $\tan(\theta) <0$ on $ (\frac{-\pi}{2},0) $ and $\tan(\theta) > 0$ on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ So this is actually an improper integral since tan isn't defined at $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ Anyways for an easier not improper integral... see below: $\int_{-8}^9 \sqrt{x^2}dx=\int_{-8}^0 -x dx+\int_0^9 x dx$ I will add the following example (which is a non-improper integral) for fun: $\int_\frac{-\pi}{3}^\frac{\pi}{4} \sqrt{\tan^2(\theta)} d \theta=\int_\frac{-\pi}{3}^0 -\tan(\theta) d \theta+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \tan(\theta)d \theta$

Comment: lol... And I had to choose an improper integral.

Comment: You could rewrite it with the bounds as $\frac{\pm \pi}{4}$

Comment: haha...awesome example, actually -- thanks again, @randomgirl :-)

Comment: True then I wouldn't have to worry about an improper integral... @zz20s